# Force a % into a textbox, aligned right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textbox that displays a percentage.  How could I somehow mask (if that's the right word) a % symbol into the textbox so that's always there and always to the far right side of the textbox?

Comment: Because `input` elements can't contain other elements (or `::before/::after` pseudo-classes), the best way might be to create a `background-image` with a % symbol that fits inside the textbox and align it right.

Comment: Most likely, `::after` pseudo-element is your best friend. But, unless you do not provide a [mcve] of your issue, chances are you won't get much help. Please note `<input>` elements cannot have pseudo-elements, you will need a wrapper for the task.

Comment: this may help https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close to what you're after?

```css
.percent-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.percent-wrapper::after {
  content: "\%";
  position: absolute;
  right: .5rem;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.percent-wrapper input {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="percent-wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="0">
</span>
```

A fancier solution is to use Bootstrap's `input-group`, but I wouldn't load Bootstrap only for this in a project:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="0">
      <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ha!  I was not aware of Bootstrap's input-group, but that is the PERFECT solution!

Comment: Bootstrap is the most popular front-end library for good reasons. Has a lot of handy tools and wrappers to solve most common UX problems and its solutions are cross-browser and cross-device. If you decide to add it to your project, take a few hours to browse its features. You won't regret it. Besides, SO is full of examples to customize it, when you need to.

Comment: Oh, it was already added.  I never start a project w/o bootstrap.  I should have mentioned it in the OP, but I just wasn't aware there was a bootstrap based solution.

Answer (score 3):

My preferred strategy is wrapping the `input` and whatever label you want in a `div` styled to look like an `input`, then remove the input styling from the `input`. I wouldn't do the widths this way on a production page, but hopefully it'll be a push in the right direction.

```css
.wrapper {border: 1px solid gray; width:110px;}
input {border:none; width:90px;}
.label {width:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="percent"/>
  <span class="label">%</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

what u need is to add the % with span and put for it position absolute left:0 top:0 this should do the trick this is the demo

```css
.row{ float: left;    position: relative;}
span {    position: absolute;    right: 0;    top: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="row"><input type="text" ><span>%</span></div>
```

Comment: looking forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Font-Awesome Icon for this `fa-percent`.
Just do this

```
1.`link to FontAwesome` 
2. in placeholder for `<input>` use the `placeholder = `HTML entity for fa-percent`
3. in your custom CSS give `font-family: FontAwesome;text-align:right;` to the input field
```

like this

```css
input {
    font-family: FontAwesome;

    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <h1>This is How you do it </h1>
 <input type = "text" placeholder = "&#xf295;">
```